# Jquery on custom-field backend

Tags: custom-field, admin, jquery

I need some help because I want to use some jquery (and css probably) on some custom fields on  post edit screen. What I need exactly is to make , and . magically apear when user types a number: types 100, jquery makes it 1,00 and so on. The custom field I created using the plugin Types and it's named wpcf-imovel-preco. I have no clue about using jquery to manipulate elements on backend :(, that alone would be great help, so i  know where to start from!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [admin_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) hook for add custom javascript files into the backend.

Comment: I'm sorry it was that simple :P